# Positioning a movieclip onto another movieclip

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I'm creating a game where if you hit a zombie the zombie dies and his head is sent back in the direction you hit. I have two movieclips the zombie and the zombie head. Once the zombie is hit it will play its dying animation and remove itself and at the same time the zombie head will be added to the dying zombie and be blown back. I have done the code for the hittest and the zombie dying and respawning but I can't seem to position and add the head to the dying zombie when it is hit. How can I do this. I thought it will be like this, I added this in the PlayDeathAnimation function in the zombie class but did not work:

```
for (var i=0; i < MovieClip(parent).zombies.length; ++i)
{
var zh = new ZombieHead();
zh.x = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].x;
zh.y = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].y;  
zh.rotation = MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].rotation;                
addChild(zh);

}
```

I have 4 classes

Player

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.display.Graphics;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;

    public class Player extends MovieClip
    {
        //Player Setting
        var walkSpeed:Number = 4;
        var walkRight:Boolean = false;
        var walkLeft:Boolean = false;
        var walkUp:Boolean = false;
        var walkDown:Boolean = false;
        var attacking:Boolean = false;
        var attackRange:int = 100;
        var attackAngle:int = 30;

        public function Player()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,walk);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,stopWalk);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,attack);
            // The lines below draw a preview of your attack area
            graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00, 0.2);
            graphics.lineTo(attackRange*Math.cos((rotation-attackAngle)/180*Math.PI),attackRange*Math.sin((rotation-attackAngle)/180*Math.PI));
            graphics.lineTo(attackRange*Math.cos((rotation+attackAngle)/180*Math.PI),attackRange*Math.sin((rotation+attackAngle)/180*Math.PI));
            graphics.endFill();


        }

        function walk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            //When Key is Down
            if (event.keyCode == 68)
            {
                walkRight = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 87)
            {
                walkUp = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 65)
            {
                walkLeft = true;
            }
            if (event.keyCode == 83)
            {
                walkDown = true;
            }
        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {

            //if attacking is true then key moves are false;
            if ((attacking == true))
            {
                walkRight = false;
                walkLeft = false;
                walkUp = false;
                walkDown = false;
                // see if the zombie is in the cone

                for (var i:int=MovieClip(parent).zombies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
                {
                    if (inAttackCone(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i]))
                    {
                        if (hitTestObject(MovieClip(parent).zombies[i]))
                        {
                            //attacking = true;
                            MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].zombieDead = true;
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            else if ((attacking == false))
            {
                //Else if attacking is false then move and rotate to mouse;
                var dx = parent.mouseX - x;
                var dy = parent.mouseY - y;
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
                rotation = angle;

                if ((walkRight == true))
                {
                    x +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkUp == true))
                {
                    y -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkLeft == true))
                {
                    x -=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if ((walkDown == true))
                {
                    y +=  walkSpeed;
                    gotoAndStop(2);
                }
            }
        }

        //Calculate the distance between the two
        public function distanceBetween(player:MovieClip,zombies:MovieClip):Number
        {
            for (var i:int=MovieClip(parent).zombies.length-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                var dx:Number = x - MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].x;
                var dy:Number = y - MovieClip(parent).zombies[i].y;
            }
            return Math.sqrt(((dx * dx) + dy * dy));
        }

        public function angleDifference(a:Object, b:Object):Number
        {
            var dx:Number = b.x - a.x;
            var dy:Number = b.y - a.y;
            var ang:Number = (a.rotation/180*Math.PI)-Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            while (ang>Math.PI)
            {
                ang -=  2 * Math.PI;
            }
            while (ang<-Math.PI)
            {
                ang +=  2 * Math.PI;
            }
            return Math.abs(ang*180/Math.PI);
        }

        function inAttackCone(enemy:MovieClip):Boolean
        {
            var distance:Number = distanceBetween(this,enemy);
            distance -=  enemy.width / 2;// account for the enemy's size
            if (distance < attackRange)
            {
                // In range, check angle
                if (angleDifference(this,enemy)<attackAngle)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        function stopWalk(event:KeyboardEvent)
        {
            if ((attacking == false))
            {
                if (event.keyCode == 68)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkRight = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 87)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkUp = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 65)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkLeft = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
                if (event.keyCode == 83)
                {
                    event.keyCode = 0;
                    walkDown = false;
                    gotoAndStop(1);
                }
            }
        }

        function attack(event:MouseEvent)
        {
            if ((attacking == false))
            {
                attacking = true;
                gotoAndStop(3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Zombies

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Zombie extends MovieClip
    {

        var walkSpeed:Number = 2;
        var target:Point;
        public var zombieDead:Boolean = false;

        public function Zombie()
        {
            //set target location of Zombie
            target = new Point(Math.random() * 500,Math.random() * 500);
        }

        function loop()
        {
            if (zombieDead == true)
            {
                playDeathAnimation();
            }
            else if (zombieDead == false)
            {
                gotoAndStop(1);
                //Point Zombie at its target
                var dx = MovieClip(root).Player01.x - x;
                var dy = MovieClip(root).Player01.y - y;
                var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
                rotation = angle;
                //Move in the direction the zombie is facing
                x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*walkSpeed;
                //Calculate the distance to target
                var hyp = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
                if (hyp<5)
                {
                    target.x = Math.random() * 500;
                    target.y = Math.random() * 500;
                }
            }
        }

        public function playDeathAnimation()
        {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }

        public function deathAnimationFinishedCallback()
        {
            for (var i=0; i < MovieClip(parent).zombies.length; ++i)
            {
                if (MovieClip(parent).zombies[i] == this)
                {
                    MovieClip(parent).zombies.splice(i, 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            MovieClip(parent).removeChild(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Document Class

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Game extends MovieClip
    {
        public var zombies:Array;

        public function Game()
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
            zombies = new Array();
        }

        public function update(e:Event)
        {
            //Only spawn a Zombie if there are less than number
            if (numChildren < 4)
            {
                //Make a new instance of the Zombie.
                var Z = new Zombie();
                addChild(Z);

                //Position and rotate the zombie
                Z.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                Z.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                Z.rotation = Math.random() * 360;

                zombies.push(Z);
            }
            for (var count = 0; count<zombies.length; count ++)
            {
                zombies[count].loop();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Zombie Head

```
package 
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;


    public class ZombieHead extends MovieClip
    {

        var headSpeed:Number = -30;
        var friction:Number = 0.9;


        public function ZombieHead()
        {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);

        }

        function Update(event:Event)
        {
                x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*headSpeed;
                y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*headSpeed;
                headSpeed *=  friction;
                if (headSpeed > -0.00001)
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                }
                else if (x<0 || x > 550 || y < 0 || y > 400)
                {
                    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Update);
                    parent.removeChild(this);
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'd just add the head as a child of the MovieClip I wanted it to travel with...

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: I did that, the head is added on but doesn't do anything, it just stays there

Comment: So, it doesn't move with the parent? I find that hard to imagine.

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: Either it doesn't work the way i want to or i get errors

Comment: What errors? What is it doing that is not the way you want?

Comment: @Amy Blankenship: what I want to do is if you hit a zombie the zombie dies and its head is sent back flying. I have done the code for zombies dying and respawning and I have done the function for the head to fly back and remove itself. Now when I add the zombiehead child in the zombie class when it is hit the head does add itself but does not perform its action it just stays static and removes itself when the zombie removes itself

Comment: OK, we're not getting anywhere. I'm not really clear on exactly what you want to happen. Sorry I couldn't help.